# Saving csv file in Latin 2 (CP852) encoding

Tags: php, csv, encoding

I have to create a csv (semicolon separated) file as export for some Česká pošta DOS based system. Its not basicaly problem, but it have to be strictly in CP852 encoding (which is extended ASCII table with czech special characters ěščřžýáíé etc. named also Latin 2). So its no solution to remove diacritics.

I tried many approches, search through stack and google, but find no working solution. Source is saved in UTF8. I try to use iconv, mb_convert_encoding and also some other libraries, but nothing works right.

Closest is to use

```
iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-2", 'abcěščřžýáíé');
```

Which looks in browser that is correctly encoded in ISO

```
abc���������
```

(when I change encoding to ISO, it shows character right).

```
abcěščřžýáíé
```

But when I write it into file by FPutS and read it again by FGetS followed by mb_detect_encoding that string, it shows UTF-8 instead. Pošta's software is very strict about encoding, so I have to make it right.

When I simply use for example

```
$text = iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII", 'abcěščřžýáíé');
```

it removes all characters with diacritics, but its not solution.

Is there anyone able to help with it? I am realy stuck ...

Comment: Central Europe code pages are CP852 / Ansi1250

Comment: Of course its 852, my mistake.